# Alternate of BufferedImage in C++

Tags: java, c++, bufferedimage

I am using BufferedImage in my Java program for storing some information in an image. The problem is that I want to create a similar program in C++ but I can't find an alternate of BufferedImage..

Looking forward to some useful ideas.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any library or any constraints on what libraries are possible as dependencies? Do you want to implement it yourself and don't know what to do? Please fix the question.

Comment: The question was fairly simple. I am looking for an alternate of BufferedImage (a class in Java) in C++.. Thanks for your comment anyways..

Comment: The question is perfectly plain, clear, and straightforward. It doesn't need to be fixed.

Comment: How is the BufferedImage going to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at the **cairo** library: http://cairographics.org/

In the examples:

```
cairo_surface_t *surface;
cairo_t *cr;
surface = cairo_image_surface_create (CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 120, 120);
cr = cairo_create (surface);
```